# Generating a table in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Why doesn't this produce a table when called from my view?  With fields_table(@user, ["id", "username"]) I am not getting the tbody's trs or tds, but I am getting everything else.

```
def fields_table(obj, fields)
  return false if obj.nil?
  content_tag(:table) do
    thead = content_tag(:thead) do
      content_tag(:tr) do
        content_tag(:td, "Property") + content_tag(:td, "Value")
      end
    end
    tbody = content_tag(:tbody) do
      fields.each do |name|
        content_tag(:tr) do
          content_tag(:td, name) + content_tag(:td, obj.read_attribute(name))
        end
      end
    end
    thead + tbody
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This code just iterates through the fields.  It doesn't return anything, so the enclosing `tbody` isn't going to have anything to content.

```
tbody = content_tag(:tbody) do
  fields.each do |name|
    content_tag(:tr) do
      content_tag(:td, name) + content_tag(:td, obj.read_attribute(name))
    end
  end
end
```

You need to return something like you do in the other parts of the code or change it to something like this:

```
tbody = content_tag(:tbody) do
  fields.map do |name|
    content_tag(:tr) do
      content_tag(:td, name) + content_tag(:td, obj.read_attribute(name))
    end
  end.join
end
```

Comment: For some reason the html is being escaped, but only in the tbody. I'm trying to debug, but maybe you know why?

Comment: Google "html_safe", somewhere in there is an untrusted string so it's no longer safe to display as is.  You can fix it by appending ".html_safe" to those methods and going from there.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend rendering a partial using the collection argument, and built in rails goodness to do this type of operation. Im guessing you want the table headings to line up with the fields? You can still do that with something along the lines of the following (havent tested, but should work),

In your model define a class method or array as constant containing the attributes you want to display on the front end, e.g.

**models/user.rb**

```
VisibleFields = [:id, :username]

#workaround for toplevel class constant warning you may get
def self.visible_fields
  User::VisibleFields
end
```

**views/users/index.html.erb**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <% User.visible_fields.each do |field| %>
      <th><%= field.to_s.titleize %></th>
    <% end %>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
<%= render :partial => 'user', :collection => @users %>
</tbody>
</table>

**views/users/_user.html.erb**

<tr>
<% user.visible_fields.each do |field| %>
  <td class="label"><%= field.to_s.titleize %></td><td class="value"><%= user.send(:field) %></td>
<% end %>
</tr>
```